# Using a shell script to replace tokens in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that holds token variables. When we switch environments we want to replace those tokens correctly for the environment we're in.

How can I do this in a Linux shell? I'm thinking awk or sed.

Example:

File has this data:

```
DB_HOST=__HOST__
DB_PASSWORD=__PASSWORD__
```

I want to read this file, recognize the `__HOST__` and replace it with the environment variable `$(HOST)`. We would get the environment variable name from the matched string between the two underscores.

Does anyone have a good idea how we could do this?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez:* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639) We are not supposed to provide LMGTFY answers, but here goes: [bash replace token in a file site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+replace+token+in+a+file+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @jww I've been researching this for hours.. I'm not trying to say give me the code per se but I just didn't list out every step i've tried.

I've tried using sed to find a pattern, i'm able to get the string from between the two underscores, how do I use that?
I tried awk, but I wasn't able to figure out how to take the underscores and replace the __DB_HOST__ with $(DB_HOST). I rarely use bash at all. I was kind of hoping that there was just a command line tool that I could use that would do this out of the box.
Stack Overflow was my last resort. I hate asking questions. Downvote if u want

Comment: @Decius: there is a commonly available command line tool which almost does this; I added it to my answer, along with some usage notes. Compensatory upvote to the question.

Comment: Personally, I think I'd just go with envsubst in its native format, unless you really really need to use underscores.

Comment: Why are you doing that instead of just having your base file be `DB_HOST=$HOST` instead of `DB_HOST=__HOST__` and then have to replace `__HOST__` with the value of `$HOST` before using it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The program `envsubst` was designed for roughly this purpose, but it wants to to use standard shell format for the strings to be substituted from the environment:

```
# Here-doc delimiter quoted to avoid having the shell do the substitutions
$ HOST=myhost PASSWORD=secret envsubst <<"EOF"
DB_HOST=$HOST
DB_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}
EOF

DB_HOST=myhost
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

`envsubst` is part of Gnu gettext, and is widely available. If you really need to use the `__...__` syntax, it would be easy to change it to `envsubst` syntax by piping through sed:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
DB_HOST=__HOST__
DB_PASSWORD=__PASSWORD__

$ sed -E 's/__(([^_]|_[^_])*)__/${\1}/g' myfile.txt |envsubst
```

Alternatively, if you have Python, there is a very simple solution:

```
from sys import stdin
from os import getenv
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"__(\w*)__")

def replacer(m):
    val = getenv(m[1])
    if val is None:
        # No such environment
        # Perhaps produce a warning, or an error
        # Here we just pass through the string unaltered
        return m[0]
    return val

print(pattern.sub(replacer, stdin.read()))
```

Example:

```
$ export HOST=myhost PASSWORD=secret 
$ python3 subst.py < myfile.txt
DB_HOST=myhost
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

The key to this solution is that Python (and only a few other languages, unfortunately) allows the replacement argument of pattern substitution to be a function, which is then called on each successive match to produce the replacement text. That makes writing functions like this easier in Python than in awk, for example, where the replacement text is fixed.

Comment: Sorry, im not super familiar with Python. How would I call this script?

Do I need to call it once per line or can I pass the entire file in?

Comment: @Decius: you pass the entire file in. I'll paste an example

Comment: The envsubst seems exactly like what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I haven't had much experience with regex. 

I noticed that this seems to match the entire word, and replaces the matched string with ${MATCH} 

However, when I run this script it seems to only replace with the last character


Example: 
    DB_CONNECTION=__DB_CONNECTION__
    DB_DATABASE=__DB_DATABASE__
returns
    DB_CONNECTION=${N}
    DB_DATABASE=${E}


It is super close but I'm not sure why \1 isn't working in sed. Any idea why it isn't substituting correctly?

Comment: @decius: my fault, i was typing in a hurry and I left out a pair of parentheses. Fixed now, I hope.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! 

If you have time could you maybe explain a bit more what the regex is doing?

I'm going to mark your answer as accepted because I think that will do the trick.

Comment: @decius: `(([^_]|_[^_])*)` is "any number of repetitions of either a character other than an underscore, or an underscore followed by a character other than an underscore". The idea is to match a string which does not contain `__`, and that's the clumsy way you need to write a regular expression for negation. Many regex libraries contain extensions (like non-greedy repetition) which do that more simply, but `sed` only implements Posix regexes.

Comment: @decius: and the parentheses around it, which I left out in the original, make `\1` capture the entire repetition (i.e. whatever is between the `__`s). `\2` (the contents of the second parentheses) is just the last repetition, which is not very useful.

Answer (score 5):

This is what `m4` is meant for:

```
$ export HOST=myhost PASSWORD=mypassword

$ cat myfile
DB_HOST=__HOST__
DB_PASSWORD=__PASSWORD__

$ m4 -D __HOST__="$HOST" -D __PASSWORD__="$PASSWORD" myfile
DB_HOST=myhost
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

If you want to autodefine macros for all environment variables, that's of course possible if slightly iffy:

```
$ cat mymacros.m4
esyscmd(`env | sed -ne "s/^\([A-Z_]*\)=\(.*\)/define(__\1__, \`\2')/p" | tr -d "\n"')

$ cat myfile2
include(`mymacros.m4')
DB_HOST=__HOST__
DB_PASSWORD=__PASSWORD__
And other arbitrary text containing things like "My editor is __EDITOR__"

$ m4 myfile2
DB_HOST=myhost
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
And other arbitrary text containing things like "My editor is vim"
```

It's not necessarily the simplest way of doing it, but it's highly flexible and extensible, with support for conditional statements, macro functions and more.

Comment: *Thinks to self "m4"? what is that?* This is exactly what I enjoy about this site, because it is true — you really can learn something new everyday. +1

Comment: This will not be a standard file. Basically I have a jenkins server and we want to be able to pass whatever we want into this. Is it possible to loop through each variable and call m4 based on what is between the two underscores?


M4 is really cool btw, I've never heard of it

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want:

```
 while IFS= read -r line  || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    from=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 1 )
    to=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 2 )
    sedString=${sedString}" s/__${from}__/${to}/g;"
  done < tokenFile.txt

sed "${sedString}" old.txt >> new.txt
```

It builds a string with all the replacements you want from tokenFile.txt, then replaces them all at once with one [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed) command, in whatever file you specify.
tokenFile.txt has your 'old=new' pairs.
old.txt is the files with **tokens**.
new.txt is where you output.

So for example, after running the script you get:

```
$ cat tokenFile.txt
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

$ cat old.txt
dbconnect __DB_HOST__

$ cat new.txt
dbconnect 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bash script cause I did not have `envsubst` available.  I used `grep` to find my token pattern then `sed` to make the replacements.  Note the use of bash [`indirect expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Given file `replace-vars.txt`:

```
Craig likes ${ENV_1}
Anuj likes ${ENV_2}
Dave likes ${ENV_3}
```

Run the following script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# env variables to replace
export ENV_1=milk
export ENV_2=cheese
export ENV_3=candy

# File to modify
declare FILE_TO_REPLACE=replace-vars.txt

# Pattern for your tokens -- e.g. ${token}
declare TOKEN_PATTERN='(?<=\$\{)\w+(?=\})'

# Find all tokens to replace
declare TOKENS=$(grep -oP ${TOKEN_PATTERN} ${FILE_TO_REPLACE} | sort -u)

# Loop over tokens and use sed to replace
for token in $TOKENS
do
  echo "Replacing \${${token}} with ${!token}"
  sed -i "s/\${${token}}/${!token}/" ${FILE_TO_REPLACE}
done
```

Output:

```
Replacing ${ENV_1} with milk
Replacing ${ENV_2} with cheese
Replacing ${ENV_3} with candy
```

Modified `replace-vars.txt`:

```
Craig likes milk
Anuj likes cheese
Dave likes candy
```